# ndarray is not C-contiguous issue by building a free program from source

Tags: linux, python-2.7, scipy, ubuntu-16.04, numpy-ndarray

I'm new for programming languages. I have build Ctrax programe from source, everything work except tracking part. The issue is a picture below:

[image: Error]

I used UBUNTU 16.04 , python 2.7.12 and others for the program requirement. According to publisher, he said it could possibly be fixed by adding `.ascontiguousarray()` after the `.astype()` call in that final line from the error message. Since you have the code compiling, you could simply try it and see if it works. (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html)

I tried it but still confuse.

Please suggest, many thanks

This is Ctrax link and requirement: http://ctrax.sourceforge.net/install.html#distutils

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.